# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen »Verpflichtung« und »Pflicht«?

Tags: difference

*Die Pflicht* oder *die Verpflichtung?* Was ist der Unterschied?

Answer (score 3):

Bei einer *Verpflichtung* spricht man bspw. von einer Aufgabe bzw. Tätigkeit, welche man erledigen muss.

Die *Pflicht* hingegen ist übergreifend. Sie entspricht einem Handeln, dem man sich auf Grund bestimmter Normen/Vorschriften nicht entziehen kann.

Answer (score 3):

Die Wörter sind nicht genau synonym, auch wenn die Überlappung recht groß ist.

Die **Verpflichtung** ist das Substantiv zum Verb "verpflichten": Sie kommt durch eine bewusste Handlung (das Verpflichten) zustande und ist somit mehr oder weniger freiwillig.

Die **Pflicht** dagegen ist nicht direkt vom Verb abgeleitet - sie kommt nicht direkt durch eine Handlung zustande, sondern wird gewissermaßen von einer anderen Quelle diktiert. Das können die eigenen moralischen Werte sein, oder auch ein gesellschaftlicher Konsens oder juristisch festgelegte Handlungsanweisungen, denen jeder folgen muss.

Es liegt natürlich oft im Auge des Betrachters, ob etwas eine "Pflicht" (Unterton: Ich muss, egal ob ich will oder nicht) oder eine "Verpflichtung" (Unterton: Ich habe mich bewusst dazu entschieden) ist, dementsprechend können sie meist füreinander ausgetauscht werden, je nach Aussageabsicht. Aber nicht immer!

> Die *Verpflichtung* (nicht: *Pflicht*) des Fußballers wurde vom Verein gefeiert.
>
> Es ist danach aber die *Pflicht* (nicht: *Verpflichtung*) des Spielers, für diesen Verein zu spielen.

Comment: Der Unterschied, den du herausarbeitest, ist vorhanden, scheint aber davon auszugehen, dass man sich grundsätzlich *selbst verpflichtet*. Die *Verpflichtung, in Deutschland Steuern zu zahlen*, z.B. kommt eindeutig von außen.

Comment: @tofro Meines Wissens heißt das in Juristisch eben genau deswegen *Steuerpflicht*, nicht *Steuerverpflichtung*. Umgangssprachlich wird natürlich wohl nicht genau unterschieden.

Answer (score 1):

Ein "Pflicht" ist eine Obligation.

Eine "Verflichtung" ist die *Anhängung* dieser Obligation.

Comment: Eigentlich eine gute Antwort, aber (insbesondere für eventuelle nicht-Muttersprachler) durch ihre Kürze nur begrenzt hilfreich. Etwas erklärender Text könnte diese Antwort in meinen Augen deutlich verbessern.

Answer (score -1):

Tatsächlich können beide Wörter synonym verwendet werden.

> "Er hatte zu viele Verpflichtungen, um sich mit so einer Lappalie herumzuschlagen"

sagt das gleiche aus wie

> "Er hatte zu viele Pflichten (zu erfüllen), um sich mit so einer Lappalie herumzuschlagen"

Sowohl "Pflicht" als auch "Verpflichtung" können ins Englische mit "duty" übersetzt werden.

Comment: A comment why you downvoted this answer would have been nice, though.